# Rtsp video streaming with authentication

Tags: java, android, rtsp, android-videoview

I'm tring to connect to straming ip cameras, with ip address. I tried to connect with:

```
rtsp://username:password@ip_camera
```

but the video view don't like it. I've tried with map like:

```
Uri source = Uri.parse("rtsp://ipcamera");
headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Username", "user");
headers.put("Password", "password");
videoView.setVideoURI(source, headers);
```

don't works anyway. So I readed on the internet that it want the base_64 basic auth so:

```
String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("username:password".getBytes(),Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP);
headers.put("Authorization", authHeader);
Uri source = Uri.parse("rtsp://ipcamera");
videoView.setVideoURI(source, headers);
```

nothing. Same error

```
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
```

that it means unknow error (?)

Any advice to find a working method?
Thanks

**EDIT**

I found, with chrome network analyze, that this camera use a Digest Authorization. That is a way to generate it?

Comment: are you sure that the key is `Username`

Comment: I'm not. Tring with username, same results.

Comment: did you try this url in VLC Player

Comment: Yes, url like rtsp://user:pass@ip work

Answer (score 4):

The library you use to stream rtsp must support digest authentication.

It isn't as simple as adding a header.

#### Digest Auth with RTSP

A Digest Enabled RTSP server should respond to a `DESCRIBE` request with `401 unauthorized` [See D.2.2](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt), returning a nonce in the `WWW-Authenticate` header, e.g.

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="GStreamer RTSP Server", nonce="1c91a068811f1029"
```

The client then uses the nonce to generate the authorization header that can be used for authentication,

```
Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="GStreamer RTSP Server", nonce="1c91a068811f1029", uri="rtsp://0.0.0.0:8554/live.sdp", response="ef18317f111b1446dc4c6a11b4f4ebf3"
```

The reponse value above is generated again per RTSP request by hashing some info as follows

```
HA1 = MD5(username:realm:password)
HA2 = MD5(method:digestURI)
response = MD5(HA1:nonce:HA2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll test it tomorrow. One question: how can I generate HA1 and HA2? I imported the spongy castle, but I don't know if it's the right path. Android studio suggest  the follow static string:
     import static org.spongycastle.bcpg.HashAlgorithmTags.MD5;